# Rust Cpal: is there a way to capture a single input channel out of 2 available on audio interface?

Tags: rust

I've been working on a voice recorder in Rust. The main issue I'm having is that my audio interface (Focusrite 2i2) has two inputs (2 channels) which are both being recorded simultaneously. What I'd like to do is to be able to select a single channel to record in mono, but I'm pretty clueless as to how to configure a single channel stream for a 2 channel device configuration.

Currently I'm using default host and default devices and configs:

```
let wav_path = "./wav.wav".to_string();

let host = cpal::default_host();
        
let input = host.default_input_device().unwrap();
let output = host.default_output_device().unwrap();
let input_config = input.default_input_config().unwrap();
let output_config = output.default_output_config().unwrap();

let sample_format = input_config.sample_format();

let input_config = input_config.config();
let output_config = output_config.config();
```

I'm getting my inputStream via make_write_stream()

```
pub type WavWriterHandle = Arc<Mutex<Option<hound::WavWriter<BufWriter<File>>>>>;
pub fn make_write_stream(input_config: &StreamConfig,
                         input_device: &Device,
                         sample_format: &SampleFormat,
                         writer:   &WavWriterHandle) -> Stream {

    let wav_writer = writer.clone();

    let input_stream: Stream = match sample_format {
        cpal::SampleFormat::F32 => input_device.build_input_stream(
            &input_config,
            move |data, _: &_| write_input_data::<f32, f32>(data, &wav_writer),
            err_fn,
        ).unwrap(),

        cpal::SampleFormat::I16 => input_device.build_input_stream(
            &input_config,
            move |data, _: &_| write_input_data::<i16, i16>(data, &wav_writer),
            err_fn,
        ).unwrap(),

        cpal::SampleFormat::U16 => input_device.build_input_stream(
            &input_config,
            move |data, _: &_| write_input_data::<u16, i16>(data, &wav_writer),
            err_fn
        ).unwrap()
    };
    return input_stream;
}
```

(I'm testing this on windows 10)

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing now that's recording both channels simultaneously? And on what platform (Linux, Windows, Mac) are you testing?

Comment: I've updated the description, I hope it helps. It's about 500 lines of code over 3 files, so if needed I can just share a link to the github project.

Answer (score 1):

I've also opened a thread on r/rust: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/s0d65g/cpal_capturing_single_channel_out_of_2_channels/

So as far as I understand cpal uses interleaved audio, which means that in case of 2 channels the data would look something like this:

```
[l,r,l,r,l,r,l,r,l,r...]
```

and in case of 8 channels:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6...]
```

So, in order to capture only R channel on 2 channel device, I'd have to capture every second sample.